# I try to use laravel echo in an application in flutter, I send message to message event , but it does not appear in the project. What is the solution?

Tags: flutter, dart, laravel-8, laravel-echo

I try to use laravel echo so I apply it I am supposed to work
knowing that I try to send a massdge to the internet it appears in blade that it is working but the application does not deliver anything what should I do to play it on the app?

https://www.mediafire.com/view/db9ozz8i7gpzqll/d.jpg/file

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before posting a question, read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask